# Как сделать вывод постов Wordpress по дате, указанной в заголовке поста? И как выводить посты с датой в заголовке >= сегодняшней даты?

Tags: php, wordpress

Я первый раз натягиваю верстку на Wordpress, поэтому прошу прощения если вопрос слишком уж простой и очевидный:

У меня на страницу выводится расписание предстоящих мастер-классов. И мне нужно чтобы посты выводились по возрастанию даты (дата указана в title поста, если это нужно - можно и пользовательское поле с датой создать).
А также нужно чтобы не выводились посты с прошедшими датами.

Подскажите, как это реализовать?

Сейчас посты выводятся вот так:

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'numberposts' => 0,
    'category_name'    => schedule,
    'orderby'     => 'title',
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'include'     => array(),
    'exclude'     => array(),
    'meta_key'    => '',
    'meta_value'  =>'',
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
  );

  $posts = get_posts( $args );

  foreach($posts as $post){ setup_postdata($post);
      ?>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="content-wrapper bg-gray schedule-card">
          <div class="day"><span><?php the_field('week_day') ?></span><span><?php the_title() ?></span></div>
          <a class="event" href="<?php the_field('mc_descr_link_1') ?>"><span class="event-time"><?php the_field('time-mc-1') ?></span><span class="event-name"><?php the_field('mc-1') ?></span></a>
          <a class="event" href="<?php the_field('mc_descr_link_2') ?>"><span class="event-time"><?php the_field('time-mc-2') ?></span><span class="event-name"><?php the_field('mc-2') ?></span></a>
          <a class="event" href="<?php the_field('mc_descr_link_3') ?>"><span class="event-time"><?php the_field('time-mc-3') ?></span><span class="event-name"><?php the_field('mc-3') ?></span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php
  }

  wp_reset_postdata(); // сброс
  ?>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо создать пользовательское поле с датой (назвать его, скажем, class_date) и сделать выборку по этому мета-полю. Замените ваш $args на следующий:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 0,
    'category_name'    => schedule,
    'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'meta_key'    => 'class_date',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'class_date',
            'value' => date("Y-m-d"), // сегодняшняя дата
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE',
            )
        ),
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
);
```